# Как заменить класс?

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Идея такая, при включении модулей дать возможность расширения стандартного класса.

Допустим, есть класс `tempClass` и я хочу расширить его, создав класс `myTemp`, но как заставить всю систему использовать новый класс?

Я придумал нечто подобное:

```
// Наследуемся от главного класса, чтоб перенять его методы, 
// ибо иначе главный класс может обновиться и тогда все сломается
class myClass extends tempClass {

}


// Регистрируем новый класс выполняющий нужную нам работу.
// Чтобы не переписывать весь код системы, в переменной хранится стандартный класс
// Выходит что-то такое: $var = new $defaultTempClass();
$defaultTempClass = ASelfPage;
```

Но проблемы начинаются, когда один из дефолтных классов расчитан на то, что от него будут наследоваться друге классы. И что-то такое уже не работает:

```
class newClass extends $defaultTempClass {

}
```

Скорей всего, я придумал жуткую дичь, так что буду рад выслушать альтернативные решения. Ну, или решения моей проблемы

Comment: "Скорей всего, я придумал жуткую дичь" - да. Но не говорите, в чем реальная проблема, чтобы мы могли вам помочь.

Comment: Надо придумать способ заменить класс, т.е. чтобы юзер не лез и не менял код в скрипте, а просто закинул файл в папку modules

Comment: Юзер вообще никогда не должен прикасаться к коду. но вы опять обрисовали не задачу, а решение.

Comment: Под юзером я подразумеваю программиста, который будет писать модуль для CMS.

Comment: И в третий раз: реальной задачи до сих пор не видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно провернуть [хитрый трюк с eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304594/1988244):

```
<?php

class A { }
class B { }
$x = 'B'; 
if( true ){ 
 $code =<<<EOF
  class C extends $x { 
    public static function bar(){
      print "baz"; 
    }
  }
EOF;

  eval( $code );
}
C::bar();
$o = new C; 
if ( $o instanceof $x )
{
  print "WIN!\n";
}
--->barWIN!
```

Но на мой взгляд это дичайший костыль.

Вместо наследования в таких случаях надо использовать Dependency Injection.

`newClass` не должен быть унаследован от `$defaultTempClass`. Он должен зависеть от передаваемого снаружи экземпляра `tempClass`. А за выбор конкретного создаваемого класса, создание экземпляра и передачу его в `newClass` должен отвечать внешний код.

Возьмите любой [готовый контейнер](http://php-di.org/) и попробуйте переписать код с наследования на вставку зависимостей.

Comment: eval я принять не могу, это уж слишком. Но почему-то не подумал о том, что могу просто использовать уже объявленный экземпляр, так и сделаю, спасибо